# GCC how to force redefinition warning to error

Tags: linux, gcc

In gcc I can pass option

```
-Werror=
```

to force a particular warning as error. But I am not able to find option I need to pass for warning

```
redefined [enabled by default]
```

to an error. 
What option should I pass so if a user defined macro is redefined it force it to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
g++ -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wunused-macros ./test.cpp
```

doesn't come up with a flag *that directly controls the emission of the warning (diagnostic)* I can only conclude that there is, in fact, no such option.

You might inquire at the gcc-devel list or file a request for enhancement.

*Alternatively, you could look at another preprocessor that has more options and use it explicitely.*